# Return an infinite tree consisting of only nodes in Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion, tree, infinite, algebraic-data-types

Given the following simple `Tree`

```
 data Tree = 
    Leaf
  | Node Tree Tree
  deriving (Eq, Show)
```

is there a way to return an infinite amount of nodes (a `Tree` with just `Nodes`, no leaves) using recursion?

So far I only know how to return data types such as `Boolean` and `Integer`. How do I start about returning a `Tree` ?

Comment: As an aside, one fun practical application of this is pure function memoization (caching, basically). Index into the tree with a binary sequence derived from the function input (e.g. right, left, right corresponds to binary 101, an integer input), and add an extra parameter to the `Node` constructor and fill it with the function result for that node's index. Then thanks to laziness, each value will only be calculated once as needed, even though the tree is infinite.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
infiniteTree :: Tree
infiniteTree = Node infiniteTree infiniteTree
```

Comment: this is also a good time to learn about [`fix`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-Function.html#v:fix): `infiniteRightTree = fix (Tree Leaf)`, `infiniteLeftTree = fix (flip Tree Leaf)`,

Comment: @rampion you meant `fix (Node Leaf)`. :)

Answer (score 2):

Another way to define infinite trees is using the [Cofree](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-4.9/docs/Control-Comonad-Trans-Cofree.html#t:CofreeF) comonad.

Infinite binary trees:

```
import Data.Functor.Product
import Data.Functor.Identity
import Control.Comonad
import Control.Comonad.Trans.Cofree

binaryTreeOfBs :: Cofree (Product Identity Identity) Char
binaryTreeOfBs = cofree $ 'b' :< Pair (Identity binaryTreeOfBs) 
                                      (Identity binaryTreeOfBs)
```

Infinite rose trees:

```
roseTreeOfBs :: Cofree [] Char
roseTreeOfBs = cofree $ 'b' :< [roseTreeOfBs]
```

You can use all the comonad functions on them, like for example [extract](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/comonad-4.2.2/docs/Control-Comonad.html#v:extract) to get the value in the head node:

```
>>> extract roseTreeOfBs
'b'
```

And you can use the [coiterT](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-4.9/docs/Control-Comonad-Trans-Cofree.html#t:CofreeF) function to unfold the trees:

```
linearRoseTreeOfIncreasingIntegers :: Cofree [] Integer
linearRoseTreeOfIncreasingIntegers = coiterT (pure . fmap succ) (Identity 1)
```